# rfcomm bluetooth on google glass

Tags: android, google-glass, android-bluetooth, google-gdk

I am having an Android-App [1] which I partly want to port to google-glass - this app uses bluetooth rfcomm. Now I am facing the following problem: when I use my connection code I see a pairing dialog on glass - showing me a large number and asks for a tap to confirm. But this is strange - as I usually have to enter my 4 digit pin on the phone - also I am getting auth problems ( smells like it is caused by not letting me enter the PIN )
Anyone using bluetooth-rfcomm on google-glass?

[1] https://github.com/ligi/DUBwise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having the exact problem like this! In this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25388643/3380233) I put my complete solution to this problem.

But basically the pairing is done like this:

In the BroadcastReceiver

```
    if(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_PAIRING_REQUEST.equals(action)){
        BluetoothDevice device = ListDev.get(selectedDevice);
        byte[] pinBytes = getStrFromName(device.getName(),7,11).getBytes();  // My devices had their own pin in their name, you can put a constant pin here or ask for one...  
        try {
            Method m = device.getClass().getMethod("setPin", byte[].class);
            m.invoke(device, pinBytes);
            try {
                device.getClass().getMethod("setPairingConfirmation", boolean.class).invoke(device, true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

So the pin is set automatically in this example, but you can always ask for a pin to the user.

Hope it helps!

Comment: thanks for the answer! Have no glass near at the moment to try it out - but this sounds like the solution I searched for