# Bluetooth Pairing Google Glass

Tags: android, bluetooth, google-glass, google-gdk

Using Google Glass, I am able to discover Bluetooth devices and see their address and information. However, I cannot get the Glass to pair (bond) with them.

### Update

Following the instructions on [this page](http://www.londatiga.net/it/programming/android/how-to-programmatically-pair-or-unpair-android-bluetooth-device/) now I'm trying to get the bonding, but for some reason the `BluetoothDevice.ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED.equals(action)` is never happening.

```
private void pairDevice(BluetoothDevice Ddevice) {
    Log.d("MY_LOG", "Try to pair " + Ddevice.getName());
    try{
        Method m = Ddevice.getClass().getMethod("createBond", (Class[]) null);
        m.invoke(Ddevice, (Object[]) null);
        Log.d("MY_LOG", "Pairing " + Ddevice.getName());
    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.d("MY_LOG", "Error: ");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

In the LOG I always get "Pairing DeviceName" but when I search for the bonded devices, it remains empty.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I will answer my own question as I just found the way.

So first, the discovery of devices is quite easy, in `onCreate()` I used (besides all other sort of code you need):

```
MyBT = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
MyBT.startDiscovery();
Filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);                    // Register the BroadcastReceiver
Filter2 = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_PAIRING_REQUEST);         // Register the Bond changing state
registerReceiver(mReceiver, Filter);                                        // Don't forget to unregister during onDestroy
registerReceiver(mReceiver, Filter2);                                       // ******
```

Then at the `BroadcastReceiver` you need to manage the devices and the pairing requests:

```
private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {           // Create a BroadcastReceiver for ACTION_FOUND
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();

        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {                      // When discovery finds a device
            BluetoothDevice BTdevice = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE); // Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent
            ListDev.add(BTdevice);                                              // Add the device to an array adapter to show...
        }     
        if(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_PAIRING_REQUEST.equals(action)){
            BluetoothDevice device = ListDev.get(selectedDevice);
            byte[] pinBytes = getStrFromName(device.getName(),7,11).getBytes();  // My devices had their own pin in their name, you can put a constant pin here...  
            try {
                Log.d("MY_LOG", "Try to set the PIN");
                Method m = device.getClass().getMethod("setPin", byte[].class);
                m.invoke(device, pinBytes);
                Log.d("MY_LOG", "Success to add the PIN.");
                try {
                    device.getClass().getMethod("setPairingConfirmation", boolean.class).invoke(device, true);
                    Log.d("MY_LOG", "Success to setPairingConfirmation.");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("MY_LOG", e.getMessage());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } 

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("MY_LOG", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
};
```

After that the device is bonded and you can manage the connection with the UUID and the sockets just as in the Android [webpage example](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html).

Hope this helps!